# custom attribute

Tags: custom-attributes, flat-catalog

I have a custom attribute which is not displayed after the activating use flat directory category, moreover, I did not activate the visible_on_ front, but I still did not get any results.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: no,My problem did not resolve

Answer (score 0):

You need to set "**use in product listing**" option from manage attributes

For Magento2

> Store -> Attributes -> Products

For Magento 1.4+

> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes

Edit your attribute. In **Storefront Properties** tab select **Used in Product Listing** to "**Yes**"

then check again after reindex

Comment: thank you,  Where is the Magento Version 1.8?

Comment: I have updated in answer, please check